# Limiting client knowledge of workflow

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Scenario:

- Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) under .NET 4
- Workflow deployed as a WCF service
- Multiple Receive operations, all with the same parameters
- Operation name matches activity name
- Using SQL Server workflow persistence
- (No SharePoint)

By default, knowledge of the workflow is embedded in the clients when you add a service reference and generate the proxy. The client knows what WCF methods are available.

I want to decouple the workflow from the clients, essentially creating a "generic" client that can work with any workflow matching certain conventions. The client would query the SQL instance store to determine what activity/operation/bookmark(s) a given instance was waiting for (this is already a standard column - ActiveBookmarks), then present that choice to the user.

This way the workflow can be changed without having to recompile/redeploy the clients. Several commercial BPM systems work this way; you can add new human client activities and they show up automatically in the client's work queue. Everything is dynamically discoverable.

How can this be done? Does it require using Reflection.Emit to generate a proxy on the fly? Would it be easier if each operation used a different service contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this in several projects and it works just fine. And no need to use Reflection.Emit as WCF has all the required infrastructure in place.

For example the following code will call the default workflow service template, all you need to do is provide the right URL.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(new BasicHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:9199/Service1.xamlx"));
        var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
        var response = proxy.GetData(new GetDataRequest() { Value = 42 });
        Console.WriteLine(response.Value);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

[ServiceContract(Name = "IService")]
interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    GetDataResponse GetData(GetDataRequest request);
}

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
class GetDataRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "int", 
        Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
class GetDataResponse
{
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "string", 
        Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

If you need more flexibility you can also create a ServiceContract with type Message in and out and a single OperationContract with Name="*" and you can handcraft your WCF message as required.

Comment: This appears to still require intimate knowledge of the workflow on the client. What if all I know is the string "[OrderEntry|{http://www.myurl.com/}IOrderEntryService: InternalReceiveMessage]" (Instances.ActiveBookmarks from InstanceStore database) and the URL? I've established a convention that the operations will take a string parameter and return void, but I don't know what operations are available in advance. Another developer could redeploy the workflow with a new OrderReview operation and my client application needs to detect and call that dynamically.

Comment: Take a look at the second part of this blog post http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/11/23/calling-workflow-services-without-add-service-reference.aspx. It describes doing the same same with a universal WCF contract and low level messaging. As long as you know what the message looks like and the URL you can send it.

Comment: When I used this I created a table in SQL Server with all the operation details I needed to create the different messages, things like parameters and return values.

Comment: thanks much for the help. It works so long as I use a message contract, but I need to use a data contract where the first parameter is the GUID the workflow correlates on and the second parameter is the data. Any suggestions?

Comment: When in doubt I use Fiddler to take a look at how the message looks on the wire using a temp client with Add Service Reference and then rebuild that using XElement and Message types. When you define 2 parameters on the wire you will still see the single message (ie MessageContract) with 2 members (ie DataContract) so that should not be any harder to create.